# C#, Powershell, undocumeted WinApi function GetFontResourceInfoW

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi

I have a AutoIt script which uses a undocumented gdi32 function (**GetFontResourceInfoW**) (Autoit: _WinAPI_GetFontResourceInfo).

It returns the name of a font file (.fon, .ttf, .ttc, etc. installed or not)
The script works perfect. I want to recode it now in Powershell.
The function prototype (from [GetFontResourceInfo](http://www.undocprint.org/winspool/getfontresourceinfo)) is:

```
BOOL GetFontResourceInfo(LPCTSTR lpszFilename, // font file name
                         LPDWORD cbBuffer,     // size of buffer for resouce information
                         LPVOID lpBuffer,      // buffer for returned resouce information
                         DWORD dwQueryType,    // resouce information query type
                        );
```

I tried the following, but it does not return the fontname.

```
$code=@'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class  FontUtil{

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")] 
        public static extern bool GetFontResourceInfoW(string lpszFilename, ref UInt32 cbBuffer, out IntPtr lpBuffer, UInt32 dwQueryType); 
}
'@
Add-Type $code

[string]$fn = 'c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf'
[Uint32]$b = 260
[IntPtr]$LocalStructPtr = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal(260)
$ret=[fontutil]::GetFontResourceInfoW($fn, [ref] $b, [ref] $LocalStructPtr,[UInt32]1)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($LocalStructPtr,$b)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($LocalStructPtr)
```

I think there is a problem with the paramaters or interop marshaling.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
out IntPtr lpBuffer
```

This is declared incorrectly. It should be:

```
IntPtr lpBuffer
```

Then the function call becomes:

```
$ret=[fontutil]::GetFontResourceInfoW($fn, [ref] $b, $LocalStructPtr,[UInt32]1)
```

You were passing the address of the pointer variable, but instead you pass that pointer variable's value. That's the address of the memory you allocated when you called `AllocHGlobal`.

Note also that your buffer has room for 130 characters rather than 260, because a UTF-16 code unit is two bytes wide. That's probably fine, but it might not be what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

For marshaling strings, `StringBuilder` is a lot more convenient than mucking around with manually allocated buffers:

```
$code=@'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class FontUtils {
    const int QFR_DESCRIPTION = 1;

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)] 
    static extern bool GetFontResourceInfoW(
        string lpszFilename, 
        [In, Out] ref int cbBuffer, 
        [Out] StringBuilder lpBuffer, 
        int dwQueryType
    );

    public static string GetFontDescription(string fileName) {
        int bufferSize = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (!GetFontResourceInfoW(fileName, ref bufferSize, sb, QFR_DESCRIPTION)) {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        sb.Capacity = bufferSize / sizeof(char);
        if (!GetFontResourceInfoW(fileName, ref bufferSize, sb, QFR_DESCRIPTION)) {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
'@
Add-Type $code

[FontUtils]::GetFontDescription('c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf')
```

Of course, it's perfectly possible to write the C# code in PowerShell as well (the marshaler isn't language dependent), I just think this is a cleaner separation of concerns.